# stationary distribution of Markov chain

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find the set of stationary distribution associated with the matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1/4&1/2&1/4\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} $$

It seems there is no unique one but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the stationary distribution is $\pi' = [a\, b\, c]$, then stationary distribution should satisfy $\pi' = \pi' P$, where $P$ is your matrix. In your case, this condition means the following condition
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\end{bmatrix}&= \begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1/4&1/2&1/4\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Doing the multiplication, you get the following conditions
\begin{align*}
    a&=a+b/4\\
    b&=b/2\\
    c&=b/4+c
\end{align*}
From the second equation $b=0$ and plugging this into the first and third we find that they are always satisfied, so $a$ and $c$ can be anything. Since $1=a+b+c=a+0+c$, we find $c = 1-a$, and the stationary distribution should be in the form $\pi' = [a \quad 0 \quad 1-a]$, where $a$ can be any number between 0 and 1. This implies that there are infinitely many stationary distributions for this system so yeah it is definitely not unique.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense!